# Facebook Insights and AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-insights, facebook-as3-api

Is there a way for me to pull data directly from Facebook Insights and load them into my Flash application instead of manually downloading the provided Excel sheet in my Fan Page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pull the data in a JSON format from the Graph API.

Checkout the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/) provided.

As far as making them useful in your Flash application, that task is up to you.